# Reformatting data frame shape in R

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I would like to reformat this data frame:

```
mydf <- read.table(
  text = "FORM   DOSE   gmean_AUC   mean_AUC   gmean_Cmax   mean_Cmax
  A      100     150         160          50           55
  B       50     70          75           30           32",
  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

into the following:

```
mydfout <-
EXPOSURE    FORM     DOSE   gmean     mean
 AUC        A       100     150       160
 AUC        B       50      70         75
 Cmax       A       100     50         55
 Cmax       B       50      30         32
```

How can I do this in R.  This reformatting would make it heaps easy for me to generate and export my Table in R.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very standard "wide-to-long" reshape question, so a good starting point would be the `reshape()` function.

```
reshape(mydf, direction = "long", idvar = 1:2, varying = 3:ncol(mydf), 
    timevar = "EXPOSURE", sep = "_")
##            FORM DOSE EXPOSURE gmean mean
## A.100.AUC     A  100      AUC   150  160
## B.50.AUC      B   50      AUC    70   75
## A.100.Cmax    A  100     Cmax    50   55
## B.50.Cmax     B   50     Cmax    30   32
```

Another option would be `melt()` from "data.table" (as opposed to `melt()` from "reshape2"):

```
melt(as.data.table(mydf), measure.vars = patterns("^gmean", "^mean"))
```

The downside is that you don't get the "AUC" and "Cmax" values, but you can reintroduce those manually with:

```
melt(as.data.table(mydf), measure.vars = patterns("^gmean", "^mean"))[
  , variable := factor(variable, labels = c("AUC", "Cmax"))][]
```

To get around this while the "data.table" team works on it, you can also try [`ReshapeLong_()` from this Gist](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/ceded54b616bdc61cb0f#file-melt-r).

The usage would be:

```
ReshapeLong_(mydf, c(gmean = "^gmean_", mean = "^mean_"), variable.name = "EXPOSURE")
##    DOSE FORM EXPOSURE gmean mean
## 1:  100    A      AUC   150  160
## 2:   50    B      AUC    70   75
## 3:  100    A     Cmax    50   55
## 4:   50    B     Cmax    30   32
```

Answer (score 3):

A solution using [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) and [tidyr](/questions/tagged/tidyr).

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mydfout <- mydf %>%
  gather(Type, Value, -FORM, -DOSE) %>%
  separate(Type, into = c("Summary", "EXPOSURE")) %>%
  spread(Summary, Value) %>%
  select(EXPOSURE, FORM, DOSE, gmean, mean) %>%
  arrange(EXPOSURE)
mydfout
#   EXPOSURE FORM DOSE gmean mean
# 1      AUC    A  100   150  160
# 2      AUC    B   50    70   75
# 3     Cmax    A  100    50   55
# 4     Cmax    B   50    30   32
```

**DATA**

```
mydf <- read.table(text = "FORM   DOSE   gmean_AUC   mean_AUC   gmean_Cmax   mean_Cmax
A      100     150         160          50           55
                B       50     70          75           30           32",
                header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Pretty neat solution. To make it even less verbose: `mydf %>%
  gather(var, val, 3:6) %>%
  separate(var, c('key', 'EXPOSURE')) %>%
  spread(key, val) %>% 
  select(EXPOSURE, everything()) %>% 
  arrange(EXPOSURE)`

Comment: @mpalanvo Thanks for sharing your solution.